# How can I escape % in a lstlisting?

Tags: listings, comments

I have a little lstlisting to show a snippet of code but since the code has % in it for modulo calculation the listing breaks down. How can I escape it?

I have tried the backslash, verbatim and `\text` commands

```
\begin{lstlisting}
int RSAEncrypt(char m)
{
    return (int)pow(charToNumber(m), e) % n;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape a % inside lstlisting... It works perfectly for me...

Comment: Could it be that you are using the `lstlisting` inside another macro or pseudo-environment like `tabularx`? Otherwise it should work fine as Seamus said. Please add a [complete minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found it, in the lstset definition I had

```
escapeinside={\%}{)}
```

I remove it and it works now. Thanks :)