# typing @ sign in lstlisting

Tags: listings

is there a way to type the "@" sign in lstlisting? I have tried just putting @ or \@ but both don't seem to work:

```
@testing
123
```

or

```
\@testing
123
```

it just outputs

```
testing123
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you add an MWE, we can reopen this question as it will be useful to other users of the site.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12768/how-can-i-escape-in-a-lstlisting - this is close to a duplicate, although if you don't know what is going on, the difference in the character that manifests the problem will make them look different.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had a `escapeinside={@}{@}` in my `\lstset` settings, so the `@` symbol did not behave as I expected.  This can be solved by changing that command so that other delimiters are used.

Comment: It'd be ideal if you could still post an MWE demonstrating the problem, so that others may fall upon this post and find the fix for themselves. :)